# Point Cloud Library - Cannot find pcl_visualizer in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, point-cloud-library, vcpkg

I installed PCL 1.11.1 (head) on Windows 10 using `vcpkg`, but it seems it doesn't include the visualizer, even when I install PCL with VTK and OpenGL support.

I get this error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h': No such file or directory

And there are no file named `pcl_visualizer.h` in my disk.

Any ideas how to solve the problem without installing PCL from source?

Here is the list of libraries installed by `vcpkg`:

```
boost                                              1.74.0
boost-vcpkg-helpers:x86-windows                    7#2             
brotli:x86-windows                                 1.0.9
bzip2:x86-windows                                  1.0.8#1
curl:x86-windows                                   7.73.0#4
curl[non-http]:x86-windows                        
curl[schannel]:x86-windows                         
curl[ssl]:x86-windows                              
curl[sspi]:x86-windows                             
curl[winssl]:x86-windows                         
double-conversion:x86-windows                      3.1.5
egl-registry:x86-windows                           2020-02-20
eigen3:x86-windows                                 3.3.7#8 
expat:x86-windows                                  2020-08-18 
flann:x86-windows                                  2019-04-07-1  
freeglut:x86-windows                               3.2.1-4 
freetype:x86-windows                               2.10.2#5      
freetype[bzip2]:x86-windows                    
freetype[png]:x86-windows            
glew:x86-windows                                   2.1.0#9     
harfbuzz:x86-windows                               2.7.2#1 
hdf5:x86-windows                                   1.12.0  
hdf5[szip]:x86-windows                        
hdf5[zlib]:x86-windows                   
icu:x86-windows                                    67.1#6
jsoncpp:x86-windows                                1.9.4
libharu:x86-windows                                2017-08-15-9
libharu[notiffsymbols]:x86-windows
libiconv:x86-windows                               1.16#6
libjpeg-turbo:x86-windows                          2.0.5#1
liblzma:x86-windows                                5.2.5#2
libogg:x86-windows                                 1.3.4#3
libpng:x86-windows                                 1.6.37#13
libtheora:x86-windows                              1.2.0alpha1-2
libxml2:x86-windows                                2.9.10#2
lz4:x86-windows                                    1.9.2-2
netcdf-c:x86-windows                               4.7.4#1
opengl:x86-windows                                 0.0#8
openssl:x86-windows                                1.1.1h#3
pcl:x86-windows                                    1.11.1#1
pcl[opengl]:x86-windows
pcl[vtk]:x86-windows
pegtl-2:x86-windows                                2.8.3
proj4:x86-windows                                  7.2.0
proj4[database]:x86-windows
proj4[tiff]:x86-windows
pugixml:x86-windows                                1.11.1
qhull:x86-windows                                  8.0.2
ragel:x86-windows                                  6.10-3
sqlite3:x86-windows                                3.33.0
sqlite3[tool]:x86-windows
szip:x86-windows                                   2.1.1-6
tiff:x86-windows                                   4.1.0
utfcpp:x86-windows                                 3.1.2#1
vtk:x86-windows                                    9.0.1#2
xxhash:x86-windows                                 0.8.0#1
zlib:x86-windows                                   1.2.11#9
zstd:x86-windows                                   1.4.5#1
```

Answer (score 2):

PCL Visualization does not currently support VTK 9.0

see discussions in https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/11462 https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/11601  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/15130

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the issues was not resolved since few months

Comment: probably waiting for https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/milestone/10