# Installation/configure/build problems with CMake and PCL

Tags: windows, cmake, vcpkg, pcl

How does vcpkg install packages, that is, where would the "right" path to the includes and libs point to? I installed `PCL` as recommended via `vcpkg` but the experience now is anything but seamless or smooth. Notice that I do use `find_package(PCL COMPONENTS common REQUIRED)` as visible in the `CMakeLists.txt` below - but I can make little sense of what it finds, so this question is mainly about thoroughly understanding what happens.

Searching manually for one of the base includes, `point_types.h`, yields three different versions - two of them appear in three(!) different directories. The CUDA version however is only present in the `buildtrees/`.

Notice: I used the posix shell only for `find`, the system is of course Windows.

```
@DESKTOP-KC7P627:/mnt/c/vcpkg$ find -name "point_types.h" -exec ls -l {} \;
-rwxrwxrwx 1 8700 Jan  3 17:25 ./buildtrees/pcl/src/pcl-1.14.0-f965f4228c.clean/common/include/pcl/point_types.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 5643 Jan  3 17:25 ./buildtrees/pcl/src/pcl-1.14.0-f965f4228c.clean/cuda/common/include/pcl/cuda/point_types.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 2541 Jan  3 17:25 ./buildtrees/pcl/src/pcl-1.14.0-f965f4228c.clean/recognition/include/pcl/recognition/point_types.h
-rwxrwxrwx 2 8700 Jan  3 17:25 ./installed/x64-windows/include/pcl/point_types.h
-rwxrwxrwx 2 2541 Jan  3 17:25 ./installed/x64-windows/include/pcl/recognition/point_types.h
-rwxrwxrwx 2 8700 Jan  3 17:25 ./packages/pcl_x64-windows/include/pcl/point_types.h
-rwxrwxrwx 2 2541 Jan  3 17:25 ./packages/pcl_x64-windows/include/pcl/recognition/point_types.h
```

Worse yet, the file that I originally wanted to include (following a toy example) was `cloud_viewer.h`, and that one is *only* found in the `buildtrees/`:

```
@DESKTOP-KC7P627:/mnt/c/vcpkg$ find -name "cloud_viewer.h" -exec ls -l {} \;
-rwxrwxrwx 1 2714 Jan  3 17:25 ./buildtrees/pcl/src/pcl-1.14.0-f965f4228c.clean/apps/cloud_composer/include/pcl/apps/cloud_composer/cloud_viewer.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 10819 Jan  3 17:25 ./buildtrees/pcl/src/pcl-1.14.0-f965f4228c.clean/visualization/include/pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h
```

The CMake PCL directories that I could identify, point to completely different directories:

```
[cmake] -- PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/eigen3
[cmake] -- PCL_DIR:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/pcl
```

Visual Studio Code finds both `<pcl/point_cloud.h>` and `<pcl/point_types.h>` but red-squiggles `<pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>`.

All in all trying PCL to get to compile in CMake is the usual frustrating mess that it always seems to be as soon as I try to lay my hands on such a library.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(pcltest)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pcl_test/pcl_startup.cpp)
# Use the following to link against all the PCL libraries
# Remove REQUIRED if PCL is not compulsory
# Note: might be heavy, not the best practice
# find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
# Prefer to use the correct component libraries instead
find_package(PCL COMPONENTS common REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS:${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS PCL_DIR:${PCL_DIR})
# All header directories not under your control go here
# ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} not required to be manually added since PCL 1.9
# include_directories(SYSTEM)
# Headers for this project go here
# include_directories(include)

# Add a target to compile for cmake
# CMake automatically chooses the correct flags for executable or library
# add_library(pcl_demo main.cpp)

# Add the required libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Pointers for a terse, very basic how-to on CMake and its inner workings (the part that you need to understand to counter such problems like above) are dearly appreciated. The CMake homepage docs are a byzantine puzzle.

Comment: "How does vcpkg install packages, that is, where would the "right" path to the includes and libs point to?" - vcpkg installs packages into `installed/` subdirectory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/reference/installation-tree-layout. If you cannot find some file there, then given file is not installed. In your case it seems that PCL is installed without "visualization" feature. You are not the first one who faced that problem. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302800/a-question-about-vcpkg-and-pcl-visualization, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312257.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, missed those. Nevertheless I find it funny that there are `buildtree` directories with obviously non-installed files in them. Package installation and build processes have degraded to a kind of black art.